# VB Script PostgreSQL pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, windows-7, vbscript, dump, pg

I'm writing a backup script in VBScript for a `PostgreSQL 9.1` database on a Window 7.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run postgresqlPath & "pg_dump.exe " & ServerId & " > " &  backupFolder & "Database.dump.out"
Wscript.Sleep 500
 objShell.SendKeys "Password~"
```

This script seems to run twice and returns no file in the destination folder.

To exclude errors in the path I had tried the command into the command-line tool, there everything worked fine as expected.

Any hints are appreciated

Comment: Use `-f file` to specify output file. And do not forget to put `"` around `backupFolder` .

Comment: Also try using the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable to pass password to pg_dump.

Comment: Hi, thanks!
backup folder is a variable for the path, so " want do no good. The SendKey is working fine, I'm also using it for createdb.exe. No Problem there. What might be a little misunderstanding in the script is the Server ID, it is actually the name of the database I want to drop.
I tried the -f option and it not working too. Even without the SendKeys I' m not asked for password, what is quite strange.

Comment: I tried to put the password into the C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf file. This works fine when I'm using the command line tool (C:/.../pg_dump.exe -U postgres DbName > C:/backupFolder/Database.dump.out). As soon as I'm using the vbscript my luck is gone.

I also tried the PGPASSWORD environment variable @IgorRomanchenko mentioned, but didn't succeed. Besides adding the PGPASSWORD into the global environment variables, do I have to add something into objShell.Run postgresqlPath & "pg_dump.exe " & ServerId & " > " &  backupFolder & "Database.dump.out"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a DOS script

`pg_dump --host 192.168.0.1 --port 5432 --username "postgres" --role "postgres" --no-password  --format plain --encoding UTF8 --inserts --verbose --file "C:\backup\mydatabase%ldt%.sql" "mydatabase"`